# C++ undefined reference to function error in g++ compiler only

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

I've looked at some of the other questions like this, but it seems like the functions should be all set up properly. Everything compiles correctly when run in CodeLite, but then compiling on a Linux server using g++, I get an undefined reference to function add_fraction, subtract_fraction, multiply_fraction, divide_fraction error in 'main.cpp' How can I fix this? Thanks!

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "header.h"


using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{

int numerator;
int denominator;
int numerator2;
int denominator2;
char operation;

cout << "Input the numerator: ";
cin >> numerator;

cout << "Input the denominator: ";
cin >> denominator;

cout << "Input the numerator2: ";
cin >> numerator2;

cout << "Input the denominator: ";
cin >> denominator2;

cout << "Input the operation: ";
cin >> operation;

if (operation != '+' || '-' || '*' || '/'){
    cout << "Please input a valid operator: ";
    cin >> operation;
}
if (operation == '+'){
    Rational addFrac;
    addFrac.add_fraction(numerator, numerator2, denominator, denominator2);
}
if (operation == '-'){
    Rational subFrac;
    subFrac.subtract_fraction(numerator, numerator2, denominator, denominator2);
}
if (operation == '*'){
    Rational multFrac;
    multFrac.multiply_fraction(numerator, numerator2, denominator, denominator2);   
}
if (operation == '/'){
    Rational divideFrac;
    divideFrac.divide_fraction(numerator, numerator2, denominator, denominator2);   
}


return 0;   
}
```

**header.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

class Rational{

public:
void reduce_fraction(int &top, int &bottom);
void add_fraction(int numerator, int denominator, int numerator2, int denominator2);
void subtract_fraction(int numerator, int denominator, int numerator2, int denominator2);
void multiply_fraction(int numerator, int denominator, int numerator2, int denominator2);
void divide_fraction(int numerator, int denominator, int numerator2, int denominator2);
};

#endif // HEADER_H
```

**header.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

void Rational::reduce_fraction (int & top, int & bottom)
{
    for (int i = top * bottom; i > 1; i--) {  
            if ((top % i == 0) && (bottom % i == 0)) {  
         bottom /= i;  
            top /= i;  
            }  

     }
 }

void Rational::add_fraction (int numerator, int numerator2, int denominator, int denominator2)
 {  
int top;
int bottom;

top = numerator2 * denominator + denominator2 * numerator;
bottom = denominator2 * denominator;

cout << "Improper Fraction -> ";
cout << top << "/" << bottom << endl;
cout << "Simplified (Rational) Fraction -> ";
if (top == bottom){
    cout << "1" << endl;
}
else {
Rational redu;
redu.reduce_fraction(top, bottom);
cout << top << "/" << bottom << endl;

}
}

void Rational::subtract_fraction (int numerator, int numerator2, int denominator, int denominator2)
{
int top;
int bottom;

top = denominator2 * numerator - denominator * numerator2;
bottom = denominator2 * denominator;

cout << "Improper Fraction -> ";
cout << top << "/" << bottom << endl;
cout << "Simplified (Rational) Fraction -> ";
if (top == bottom){
    cout << "1" << endl;
}
else {
Rational redu;
redu.reduce_fraction(top, bottom);
cout << top << "/" << bottom << endl;

}
}

void Rational::multiply_fraction (int numerator, int numerator2, int denominator, int denominator2)
{
int top;
int bottom;

top = numerator * numerator2;
bottom = denominator * denominator2;

cout << "Improper Fraction -> ";
cout << top << "/" << bottom << endl;
cout << "Simplified (Rational) Fraction -> ";
if (top == bottom){
    cout << "1" << endl;
}
else {
Rational redu;
redu.reduce_fraction(top, bottom);
cout << top << "/" << bottom << endl;

}
}

void Rational::divide_fraction (int numerator, int numerator2, int denominator, int denominator2)
{
int top;
int bottom;

top = denominator2 * numerator;
bottom = numerator2 * denominator;

cout << "Improper Fraction -> ";
cout << top << "/" << bottom << endl;
cout << "Simplified (Rational) Fraction -> ";
if (top == bottom){
    cout << "1" << endl;
}
else {
Rational redu;
redu.reduce_fraction(top, bottom);
cout << top << "/" << bottom << endl;

}   
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g

default: main

search: main.cpp
${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} main.cpp -o search
clean: 
rm -f *.o main
```

Comment: What function does it say is undefined?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should look into making the functions in Rational.hpp static since they don't rely on any member variables. Instance creation is unnecessary unless you want to store `numerator` and `denominator` within the class.

Comment: … or better, replace `class Rational` with a namespace.

Comment: It says add_fraction, subtract_fraction, multiply_fraction, divide_fraction are all undefined. Also, thanks for the help about static, I may use that.

Comment: `if (operation != '+' || '-' || '*' || '/')` does not do what you think of

Comment: What does it do @billz ? Seems to work when I test an incorrect operator.

Comment: I believe it always return true

Comment: Yeah, it seems to asking "Please re-enter operator" even when the input is correct. So I input + then it still says re-enter, then it runs. Any suggestions on a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not building `header.cpp` at all.  It's not mentioned in your Makefile.  You need to compile it and link it into your executable.  Try this:

```
search: main.cpp header.cpp
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} main.cpp header.cpp -o search
```

Comment: I just updated it like you suggested, but that didn't fix anything. I'll edit my post with those changes in my makefile.

Comment: The other problem is that you use the name `main` in your `Makefile` where you should say `search`.  That error is in two places: `default` and `clean`.  Fix this, and your code works.

Comment: Okay, I changed default: main to default: search then clean: to rm -f* .o search but now I'm getting a Clock skew detected error. even after restarting the connection to the server. Code updated on original post for makefile.

Comment: @austinscode: that's a system administration problem.  I suggest you post it as a new question, as it has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: Ahh, finally got it to work. Forget to do "make clean" instead of just make. Thanks for the help guys!